# Django 1.8 HStore field throwing Programming Error

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, django-1.8

I'm following the code in the documentation

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = HStoreField()

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

Running this code results in:

```
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

I'm using Postgres==9.3.6, psycopg2==2.6, and I've checked that the HStore extension is enabled.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ensure you add `'django.contrib.postgres'` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 1):

> Ensure you add 'django.contrib.postgres' to settings.INSTALLED_APPS.

And the order is important!
Put it over the other django.contrib APPS